# Can't seem to add additional GLTF markers to my map (WebGL)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add a number of GLTF markers to my map in the new WebGL by Google Maps Platform.

I can't seem to change the location of them? I can add another marker but it is shown in exactly the same place as the previous marker and I can't move it or change it's location (lat & lng)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the video and read the blogs in the description. I hope this will solve you error.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMtE2xooVcA&t=2s)

Cheers!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29969972)